# How to do left outer join on columns containing array.

Tags: database, postgresql, left-join

I have something like this.

\d Table1

```
uid |int (primary key)
name|text
cids|int[]
```

example:

```
id   | name  | cids 
 1   | joe   |{10,20,30}
 2   | marry |{10,20,30,40}
 3   | john  |{30,40}
```

\d Table2

```
cid   |int (primary key)
name  |text
type  |int
```

example

```
cid  | name  |  type
10   | aname | 0  
20   | bname | 0
30   | cname | 1
40   | dname | 0
```

Now i wanted a result like 
    id, name  from table1 and cid , name from table 2. where type !=1

```
Example. 
id | name | cid      |cnames
1  | Joe | {10,20}   |{aname,bname}
```

Please tell me what is the efficient way to do this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
For Versions < 9.0

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, 
array_agg(b.cid) cids,array_agg(B.name) cnames
FROM Table1 A
JOIN 
(
  SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY cid
)
B ON B.cid = ANY(A.cids)
WHERE type <> 1
GROUP BY A.id, A.name;
```

(Following Works for version 9+)

```
SELECT A.id, A.name, 
array_agg(b.cid order by b.cid) cids,
array_agg(B.name ORDER BY B.name) cnames
FROM Table1 A
JOIN Table2 B ON B.cid = ANY(A.cids)
WHERE type <> 1
GROUP BY A.id, A.name
```

[SQL DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/c3570/14)

Comment: Thanks for ur help. 
But i am getting syntax error. 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ORDER"

Comment: @Qstacker which version are you using?

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated. I am on Postgresql 8.3.4. and i get the following error when i try <9 version of ur code. I can see the results exactly how I wanted in SQL Demo for other postgres versions.

Error :  ERROR: syntax error at or near "cids": SELECT A.id, A.name, array_agg(b.cid) cids , array_agg(B.name) cnames FROM Table1 A JOIN ( SELECT * FROM Table2 ORDER BY cid ) B ON B.cid = ANY(A.cids) WHERE type <> 1 GROUP BY A.id, A.name (8.3.20 in sqlfiddle shows the exact error i am getting). Thanks